# 500 ReferenceError: schoolpp is not defined (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello I have 3 file in my express nodejs application :
file FactorySchool.js:

```
 require("./OBforSchool.js");
function FactorySchool () {
}
FactorySchool.prototype.dofingSchool = function () {
        console.log(this.message);
        return this.message;
    };
 FactorySchool.factorySchool = function (fncontrol) {
        var contr = fncontrol[1];
        var varSchool;
        if (typeof FactorySchool[contr] != "function") {
            console.log("Undifine function");
        } else {
            if (typeof FactorySchool.prototype.dofingSchool != "function") {
                FactorySchool[contr] = new FactorySchool();
            }
            varSchool = new FactorySchool[contr](fncontrol[0]);
        }
        return varSchool;

    };

 //--------------------DEfine method to process school
    FactorySchool.addBlockSC = function (OBblock) {
        return this.message = "add OK";
    }
    FactorySchool.deleteSC = function (OBblock) {
        this.message = "dekete OK";
    }
```

file School.js

```
 //file School.js to call
    var facschool = require('./FactorySchool');
        var obchool = require('./OBforSchool');
        exports.school = function (req, res) {
            var obsc = new Object();
            var detailSchoolob = new Object();
            detailSchoolob.firstname = "Thai";
            detailSchoolob.lastname = "Ngo";
            obsc.agr1 = "addBlockSC";
            obsc.agr2 = detailSchoolob;
            var a = new facschool.FactorySchool.factorySchool(obsc);
            console.log(a);
            a.dofingSchool();

        };
```

when I call

> var a = new facschool.FactorySchool.factorySchool(obsc);

I received a error :`500 TypeError: Cannot read property 'factorySchool' of undefined`

How i can fix it.
 Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

you define `FactorySchool.factorySchool` inside the `FactorySchool` constructor.
You should call it before access to property defined.

However it would be better if you define it outside the constructor.

Comment: Thanks @chumkiu I'm edit my FactorySchool.js file and my problem is School.js. I can't call from FactorySchool.js because I received "undefined".

Comment: `FactorySchool.factorySchool` is not a prototype. So you should call it with `FactorySchool.factorySchool` and not `facschool.FactorySchool.factorySchool`